# use of module dw::tests::Asserts in DataWeave

Tags: dataweave

Hi I am trying to use dw::tests::Asserts in DataWeave playground  and it's showing error i.e `unable to resolve module with identifier`

Example

```
%dw 2.0
import dw::tests::Asserts
---
payload
```

Could anybody help how to put module in a DataWeave script

Comment: That module is only supposed to be used with MUnits and therefore it is not included in the mule runtime by default. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I believe it should be pretty obvious that if you are asking for help in using something you should be providing the details of what you are doing, not just the error. Please read in detail https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to write a good question. Having said that, in this particular case as @HarshankBansal said whatever you are trying to do will never work in DataWeave Playground because your are trying to use modules that are only intended to be used for MUnit tests and not in standalone scripts.

Comment: @HarshankBansal actually this could be useful to others that are not aware of the usage that module. You should write an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @aled I was hoping to get a more clear requirement before posting an answer. looks like can't happen

Answer (score 1):

The assert module is only supposed to be used with MUnits and therefore it is not included in the mule runtime by default. Therefore it is also not included with the [DataWeave Playground](https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/).

If you want to assert something you can use the [validation module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/validation-connector/2.0/). It contains multiple validation options.
For example, you can use [`validation:is-not-blank-string`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/validation-connector/2.0/validation-examples#configure-the-is-not-blank-string-operation) to "assert" a string is not null.

```
<validation:is-not-blank-string value="#[payload.username]" message="The username cannot be blank"/>
```

---

Alternatively, if you have to have the validations within DataWeave for some reason, you can use the [`failIf`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-runtime-functions-failif) function of the Runtime module. 
A small problem with this is that the error is always going to be a `MULE:EXPRESSION` error and you will have to rely on the description in your error handler if you want to handle that error separately. 
Below is an example of this. You can also test this in DataWeave Playground:

```js
%dw 2.0
import failIf from dw::Runtime
output application/json
---
{
     "result" : failIf( payload.username, //This is passed to the function in the second argument. It is also the result of the function if the failIf condition is false.
                        (username) -> isEmpty(username), // The actual check. This should always result to a boolean value
                        "Username cannot be empty" // Error description to show if the validation fails.
                    ) 
}
```

Comment: Very good and detailed answer!